# Stuck with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Am unable to find the real problem with my code. Am using the same code for all other APIs and everything working fine but one API is giving problem.

```
    NSString *strUrl = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURL,apiURL] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval:30.0];

    //request type may be "POST" or "GET"
    [request setHTTPMethod:requestType];
    [request setValue:secretKey forHTTPHeaderField:key];

    //contentType may be "application/json" or "text/html"
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [requestOperation setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        completion(nil);
    }];

    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
        completion(nil);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        completion(nil);
    }];
```

This code is working for all APIs except one. It's giving me this error in error block.

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"
```

I have then tried to add the acceptable content type by doing this.

```
requestOperation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [requestOperation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```

This did not work. Then i changed the response serializer to AFHTTPResponseSerializer and removed the acceptable content types line. Then the response came as NSData and I parsed the NSData response to JSON object for all other APIs. But this API is giving this error after changing the response serializer. Here is the error from error block.

```
JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.
```

Am not getting this why this happening. I have tried to change the header acceptable content type to json and html. But those are not making any difference. I have tried the API in Chrome Postman and it's working absolutely fine. Please suggest something, where am doing wrong.

Comment: when i tried with postman the json text was fully formatted and i got no error in formatting. But when am trying with AFNetworking it's coming in error block. and the response is nil

Comment: Please check my question. First am using the AFJSONRequestOperation but its giving error that acceptable content type is text/html and i found by searching in stack and github that if i use the AFHTTPResponseSerializer then this error will be solved. But it raised another error.

Answer (score 0):

Set Content-type to application/Json and try

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];